# Log file mechanism

Tags: c++, logging

I want to create a generic log file which I can easily reuse in multiple files. Also, I want to be able to use the versatile `std::cout` so I can easily write formatted text (as oppose to create my own write function which may write only strings and which can probably never be that versatile).

Definition

```
#include <fstream>

class logstream :
    public std::ofstream
{
public:
    logstream();
    ~logstream();

protected:
    std::streambuf *psbuf, *backup;
    std::ofstream filestr;
};
```

Implementation

```
logstream::logstream()
{
    filestr.open("test_streaming.txt", std::ofstream::app);

    backup = std::clog.rdbuf();     // back up cout's streambuf

    psbuf = filestr.rdbuf();        // get file's streambuf
    std::clog.rdbuf(psbuf);         // assign streambuf to cout
}


logstream::~logstream()
{
    std::clog.rdbuf(backup);        // restore cout's original streambuf

    filestr.close();
}
```

Usage:

```
void CExportDlg::OnBnClickedButtonLog()
{
    logstream log; // redirects clog and restores it when it goes out of scope

    std::clog << "hello this goes into log file" << std::endl;
    std::clog << "And I can readily write intetgers like " << 5 << "this one" << std::endl;
}
```

In reality, I have put the line `logstream log` in the main application class so now I can use only `std:clog()` anywhere in the application and output goes to a log file. But can this be improved?

What if I want to create multiple log files for different purposes? Is there a way I can access `clog()` (or `cout()`) by the object so it goes into that object only, like `log.clog()`?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1761027/14065

Answer (score 3):

I like how you use the existing stream API instead of rolling your own. Also I think that redirecting `std::clog` is a good approach as this could then easily be retro fitted into an existing application that properly uses `std::clog` with ease.

However there are some problems.

## Usage

The inheritance of from `std::ofstream` implies a usage such as this:

```
logstream log("logfile.txt");
log<<"foobar\n";
```

but this is not the intended usage of the class. I also see no reason why this class must inherit from `std::ofstream`. I would remove this inheritance because in my opinion it breaks the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

## Scoped design

While a scoped design is good in some/many cases I don't think this is one of them. Typically logging destinations is not something you configure per scope but rather once for the application. This is merely a personal opinion I'm sure it has its uses.

## Usability

I'm missing some features. One particular that comes to mind is to write to file and console at the same time (as the example by @LokiAstari [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1761027/14065)).

## Consider using an already existing library

Like for example [log4cpp](http://log4cpp.sourceforge.net/) which provides log streams which you can redirect `std::clog` to and use separately. It is configurable and has all the bells and whistles you usually want from a log system.

Comment: `auto log = logstream("logfile.txt");` doesn't build even though I added parameter to constructor to take filename.

Comment: You need move constructor for it to work. I was just illustrating an example

Comment: Can you post it here?

Comment: @zadane This is "*code review*" not "*write code for me*". If you need help writing a move constructor ask in stackoverflow.